# Python decorator-like design pattern for Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, callback, decorator

I'd like to have common try/catch/finally logic in a decorator-like feature that can "wrap" a function or class method. Consider the scenario:

```
Class MyClass {
  void someMethodA() {
    doSomeInitialWork();
    
    try {
      doSomething();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    } finally {
      doSomeCleanUpWork();
    }
  }

  void someMethodB() {
    doSomeInitialWork();
    
    try {
      doSomethingElse();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    } finally {
      doSomeCleanUpWork();
    }
  }
}
```

So on and so forth. The unique parts of each method are just the `try` body. If I have a bunch of methods, some which require the same logic, is there a "nice" way to avoid redundant code?

Ideally it could be syntax like:

```
@wrapper
void someMethodA() {
  doSomething();
}

@wrapper
void someMethodB() {
  doSomethingElse();
}

MyClassInstance.someMethodA(); // call it like this and the wrapper takes care of everything
```

but I know those are annotations in Dart and not applicable here.

**UPDATE**

Following jamesdlin answer, I am trying to incorporate the anonymous function solution to a futures/async/await scenario:

```
Future<dynamic> trySomething(Future<dynamic> Function() callback) async {
  doSomeInitialWork();

  try {
    return await callback();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    doSomeCleanUpWork();
  }
}

class MyClass {
  Future<List<String>> someMethodA() async {
    return await trySomething(() async {
      return await someApiCall();
    });
  }
}
```

That seems to work, but it looks kind of messy. I'm not sure if what I'm doing in the async/await example is appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous functions in Dart are rather common (unlike Python, where `lambda` is very restricted).

You therefore could make a helper function that takes the unique part as a callback.

```dart
void trySomething(void Function() body) {
  doSomeInitialWork();

  try {
    body();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    doSomeCleanUpWork();
  }
}

void someMethodA() {
  trySomething(() {
    doSomething();
  });
}

void someMethodB() {
  trySomething(() {
    doSomethingElse();
  });
}
```

That's basically what `test()` from `package:test` (or `testWidgets()` from Flutter) do.

---

Update for the case described in the comment: It's not much different if the methods return `Future`s.  For example, if you start with:

```dart
Future<List<String>> someMethodA() async {
  return await blah();
}
```

then you could do:

```dart
Future<R> trySomethingAsync<R>(Future<R> Function() body) async {
  doSomeInitialWork();

  try {
    return await body();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  } finally {
    doSomeCleanUpWork();
  }
}

Future<List<String>> someMethodA() {
  return trySomethingAsync(() async {
    return await blah();
  });
}
```

Comment: To make things a bit more complicated, what if the methods return futures? So instead of `void someMethodA() {}` it is `Future<List<String>> someMethodA() async {return await blah();}`. I'm not sure what the anonymous function looks like now and how to wrap the body.

Comment: @user1087973 Sorry, I didn't see your comment before.  If you haven't figured it out on your own yet, I've updated my answer for your case.